# The basic style for make this layot

Tags: css

It looks like a table, but I'd like to implement it by using only CSS.

What is the most robust style for this layout that works with all browser?

```
        _________
        | A |__b__|
        |_A_|__c__|

<div class='container'>
        <div class='sectA'> A </div>
    <div>
        <div class="sectB"> b </div>
        <div class="sectC"> c </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Semantics aside, if it looks like a table, acts like a table, and maybe even smells like a table, use a table.  There are no "robust styles that works with all browsers" for this.  If you need info on the appropriate CSS properties to use to get started on a non-crossbrowser-friendly solution: **[click here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display)**

Comment: I think there's a strong case for using actual tables for tabulated data!

Comment: even though I answered I still agree that tables may well be the way to go here. Depends on the content though, this could easily be a layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one more div and two more classes, but it's very easy:

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
        <div class='sectA'> A </div>
    <div class="separator">
        <div class="sectB"> b </div>
        <div class="sectC"> c </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container div.sectA
{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px dotted #000;
}

div.separator
{
    float: left;
}

div.sectB,
div.sectC
{
    float: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px dotted #f00;
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

[Click here for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/bSz9T/).