# bootstrap basic layout: image in left of content div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm now starting with Botsraf.
I have a basic layout the following content:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg" />
  <div>
      <h1>a title</h1>
      <p class="lead">
          a sub title, sub title, sub title....
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

live example: http://www.bootply.com/DSuDe10sGW

i want the image float in left, and the title & sub title in right. ant the height `jumbotron` div fit the picture (or the div content, the highest). like:

```
|      |  title
| img  |  sub title.. sub title.. sub title..
|      |  sub title..
```

like this qustion [The basic style for make this layot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7419578) but in right way using bootstarp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap it's called media defaults
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media-default

Your code is going to be something like:

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/9o4rzpw6/)**

```
<div style="margin-left: 325px;margin-top: -179px;">
```

This full code

```
  <div class="jumbotron">
          <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg">
          <div style="margin-left: 325px;margin-top: -179px;">
              <h1>a title</h1>
              <p class="lead">
                  a sub title, sub title, sub title....
              </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```